# is bassistance jquery form validation still the De facto form validation?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I havent looked at doing serious form validation in jquery for a few years now, but google reveals that bassistance's validation plugin is still on top for "jquery form validation".

Is this what most people still really use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, yes it's still the most used.

Also I'm seeing the [jQuery Tools validator](http://flowplayer.org/tools/validator/index.html) is gaining popularity.

Comment: i like that validator for some reason

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) is still by far the most used/supported validation plugin, but there *are* alternatives as well (none nearly as mature though).  It also has the benefit of being hosted on Microsoft's CDN, for example: http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js

There's a populate tag on SO for it as well, 612 questions when I just tagged yours with it: [jquery-validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate)